os-prober will not detect windows at all
I have a computer with ubuntu22 and windows 10 installed in seperate ssd disks, and I have used dual boot feature for a while. However after reinstalling the ubuntu 22, I have lost ability to boot to windows.
This is not about grub running os-prober at boot time. After boot and login to ubuntu 22,
I run os-prober and it returns nothing. I have also run boot-repair, and boot repair will complain about LegacyWindows being detected, but NO this is completely wrong since this computer has always been in UEFI mode, and windows was installed with UEFI mode from the start.
Here is the pastebin for the boot-repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mjZTvxtprS/
and as you can see, the windows partition has GPT and not MBR.
Any ideas/help/recomendations greatly appreciated.
Best Regards,
C.

I see no bootloaders at all listed in your EFI partition on nvme0n1p1, but there is some mount error.  If you'd formatted the parttiion while installing ubuntu, the Windows bootloaders would be missling, like we see, but without the ubuntu bootloaders, I don't see how you can boot ubuntu (unless the error prevented them from listing). Mount the partition (fs type fvat) and look: are there  EFI/ubuntu and EFI/Microsoft, and EFI/Boot directories?

Do you per chance have 2 EFI Partitions? One on the Windows Drive and one on the Ubuntu Drive.  If you or the Ubuntu Installer accidently deleted the partition on the Windows drive, you need to restore it, using the procedure outlined here.  Use the answer I linked to, not the Accepted Answer.

Your UEFI entries shows two different GUID/partUUID to find ESP. But you only show one ESP on system. Or you probably reformatted the ESP on the NVMe drive, erasing the Windows boot files. You need a Windows repair/recovery flash drive or installer with repair console to restore the Windows boot files to ESP. Or add new ESP to sda & create Windows boot files into that ESP.
